# Set a semi transparent box when burning vobsubs to MP4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-subtitles

I'm using ffmpeg to convert some old videos. Some have VobSub subtitles, so I am hardcoding them in. Is there a way to add a semi transparent box behind the subtitles for easier reading?

Comment: Those subtitles have a .idx file, right? To improve readability, have you tried changing the palette in that file? Or instead of drawing a box, would it be possible to burn the same subtitles all in black and a little bit bigger and then burn them again all in white?

Comment: You can use drawbox filter to make a transparent box, but timing it with the subtitles would be tedious. Here's an [example](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/15554) for a single phrase.

Comment: @Hernán No idx that I know of. They're embedded in an mkv file.

Comment: @llogan Thank sounds like a lot of timing. I thought maybe it'd do it by itself. Thanks. I'll just leave as is.